# spark saveAsTextFile method is really strange in java api，it just not work right in my program

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am new to spark and  get this problem when i run my test program。I install spark on an linux server，and it has just one master node and one worker node。Then I write test program on my laptop，code like this:

```
     `JavaSparkContext ct= new JavaSparkContext ("spark://192.168.90.74:7077","test","/home/webuser/spark/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4",new String[0]);
    ct.addJar("/home/webuser/java.spark.test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar");
    List list=new ArrayList();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(6);
    list.add(9);
    JavaRDD<String> rdd=ct.parallelize(list);
    System.out.println(rdd.collect());
    rdd.saveAsTextFile("/home/webuser/temp");
    ct.close();`
```

I suppose I could get /home/webuser/temp on my server ,but in fact this program create c://home/webuser/temp in my laptop which  os is win8,I don't understand,
shouldn't saveAsTextFile() run on spark's worker node?why it just run on my laptop,which is sprak's driver,I suppose.

Comment: by the way ,I didn't use spark-submit to run this program.I run it as an application in my IDE.I didn't plan to run my application by spark-submit so I test it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which filesystem is the default for your Spark installation. According to what you're saying the default filesystem for you is `file:///` which is the default. In order to change this, you need to modify the `fs.defaultFS` property in `core-site.xml` of your Hadoop configuration. Otherwise, you can simply change your code and specify the filesystem URL in the code, i.e.:

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://192.168.90.74/home/webuser/temp");
```

if `192.168.90.74` is your Namenode.

Comment: thanks for your reply。In fact i just want to test my program by saving my rdd to local file ，not to hdfs。I run my program on my laptop and spark is installed on my server with it's ip “192.168.90.74”，which is both master node and worker node。I'm wondering why this program create localfile on my laptop in directory “/home/webuser/temp” ，not on the server？The method saveAsTextFile should run and create file on worker node ,isn't it?I'm new to spark programming and don't know weather i'm clear,thanks for your help

Comment: It is creating it on the local machine because the filesystem is `file:///` and the driver program runs on your local machine. If you want to store it on the server local filesystem use `file://192.168.90.74/...`.